# Shell Script to compute hash for every X bytes

Tags: bash, shell-script, hashsum

I have a file of size 128KB, and would like to compute SHA256 hash for every 32KB. i.e

```
Hash 1 - Start of file - Start of file + 32KB
Hash 2 - 32KB - 64KB
Hash 3 - 64KB - 96KB
Hash 4 - 96KB - 128KB
```

I am able to compute on a whole file using sha256sum , but couldn't generate on portions of file from script.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU `split`:

```
for i in {1..4}; do
  split -n"$i"/4 file | sha256sum
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `split --bytes=$((32*1024))` to generate the four file portions, then hash them individually.